# React-router is not displaying anything in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a simple meetup application using React.The folder structure is as below:
[image]

Inside AllMeetups.js:

```
function AllMeetupspage(){
return <div>AllMeetups</div>
}

export default AllMeetupspage;
```

Inside Favourites.js:

```
function Favouritespage(){
    return <div>favourites</div>
    }
    
export default Favouritespage;
```

Inside Newmeetup.js,

```
function NewmeetupPage(){
    return <div>Newmeetup</div>
    }
    
export default NewmeetupPage;
```

Inside App.js,

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import AllMeetupspage from './pages/AllMeetups';

import NewmeetupPage from './pages/Newmeetup';

function App() {
  return (
    
    <div>
      <Route path='/'>
        <AllMeetupspage />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/new-meetup'>
        <NewmeetupPage />
      </Route>    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Inside index.js,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I want to see the Allmeetups page content when I load browser.But when I load the browser,it displays nothing.I am new to react and javascript.Could anyone please let me know where I go wrong?

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: which version of react-router are you using in your project?

Comment: If you are using latest version of react router dom, then there is a slight change. I have just re-created your code, please check this. if it works let me know https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-dawn-80cd1

Comment: @Learner-Yes,it works...Thanks so much.As you said,there must be a slight change to the new version.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using react-router @v6, you need to replace `component` with `element`

```
<Route path="/" element={<AllMeetupspage />} />
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap your routes with the BrowserRouter ( in the below image used as Router) from the react-router-dom for the routing to work. I think this is the issue in your code, sorry if am wrong.

Eg:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
return (
    <>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </>
);
};

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router version@5 or lower you need to do

`<Route exact path="/new-meetup" />`

because both routes start with the "/" and would always fall back to the first as you don't specify that you want the complete URL match.  The exact parameter basically is some kind of regex that says should match the complete url. From the old docs: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool
With the version@6 its not necessary anymore as react-router by default will always look for the exact path.